# expected ‘uint32_t’ but argument is of type ‘uint32_t *’

Tags: c

I am new in C, trying to call a function, but it gives me error that I can not understand why

> int set_price(&colour->type.name);

it returns me `expected ‘uint32_t’ but argument is of type ‘uint32_t *’.  warning: passing argument  ‘int set_price’ makes integer from pointer without a cast`

where the pointer is

> house_list *colour = NULL;

and
name is defined in struct as

> uint32_t name;

the original function accept

> > int set_price(uint32_t name) 
> >  { 
> > /*do something here*/
> >  }

what do I do wrong? If in the struct member, name is defined as uint32_t, and I defined a pointer colour, than I believe that I need to use & before colour->type and use dot before name isn't it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set_price(&colour->type.name);
```

remove the & and you'll be fine

```
set_price(colour->type.name);
```

`set_price` expects an integer as an argument, not a pointer to integer.

I suggest that you should read [a good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).